# Direct Data Access within Directus for external PHP script

Tags: php, directus

I'm trying to access collections and data stored within Directus (decoupled PHP CMS) without having to perform a cURL to my own server. Their documentation states that this is possible with their [Item Service API](https://docs.directus.io/advanced/api/data.html#fetching-data-within-hooks-and-endpoints). The point of the external script would be to perform operations on the datasets that should not be performed as a part of a Hook. In essence, **I am trying to access Directus directly using PHP by specifying the install directory**. *The issue is that the specific configuration of the target project is never loaded*, nor able to be specified in any way. As a result, the following code:

```
<?php

$directus_dir = __DIR__ . "/directus/src/web.php";
include_once $directus_dir;


$container = \Directus\Application\Application::getInstance()->getContainer();
$itemsService = new \Directus\Services\ItemsService($container);

echo "<pre>".print_r($itemsService, True)."</pre>";

$params = [];
$items = $itemsService->findAll('directus_users', $params);
$item = $itemsService->find('directus_users', 1, $params);
```

Will always fail to "findAll". Instead, $itemsService will return the following below. **The [database] array will never populate with values corresponding to the project.**

```
Directus\Services\ItemsService Object
(
    [container:protected] => Directus\Application\Container Object
        (
            [defaultSettings:protected] => Array
                (
                    [httpVersion] => 1.1
                    [responseChunkSize] => 4096
                    [outputBuffering] => append
                    [determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware] => 
                    [displayErrorDetails] => 
                    [addContentLengthHeader] => 1
                    [routerCacheFile] => 
                )

            [values:Pimple\Container:private] => Array
                (
                    [settings] => Directus\Collection\Collection Object
                        (
                            [items:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [httpVersion] => 1.1
                                    [responseChunkSize] => 4096
                                    [outputBuffering] => append
                                    [determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware] => 
                                    [displayErrorDetails] => 
                                    [addContentLengthHeader] => 1
                                    [routerCacheFile] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [config] => Closure Object
                        (
                            [static] => Array
                                (
                                    [appConfig] => Array
                                        (
                                            [app] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [env] => production
                                                )

                                            [env] => production
                                            [logger] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [path] => E:\APPS\LaragonPortable\www\directus\logs
                                                )

                                            [database] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => mysql
                                                    [host] => localhost
                                                    [port] => 3306
                                                    [name] => directus
                                                    [username] => root
                                                    [password] => root
                                                    [engine] => InnoDB
                                                    [charset] => utf8mb4
                                                    [socket] => 
                                                )
```

How does one specify the project and config.php details to be loaded? How does one use this API? (as the documentation only outlines find() and findAll()) A PHP SDK exists, but has not been updated in 2 years.

Thanks in advance.